# Hyperlink on ordered list

Tags: list, hyperlink

Thanks for reading this question. I am having a little problem with regards to my ordered list at the bottom of these code under  tag. On my preview, it is showing my contact.html url. Have I missed something here?

Here are my full website code and I am currently working on:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lan="en-US">

<head>
    <title>Mobile Website Builder</title>
</head>

<body>  

    <header id="page_header">
            <h1>Wiltshire Mobile Website Builder</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</li>
                <li><a href="services.html">Services</li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </header>

    <img src="mobileconversion.JPG" />

<section>

    <article>
        <p><strong>Wiltshire mobile website</strong> is a mobile and multi-screen website builder for businesses. We also provide SEO services for your marketing needs.</p>
        <p>
            <h3>Why us?</h3>
            <ol>
                <li>Search engine friendly mobile & multi-screen website</li>
                <li>Attractive design</li>
                <li>Search engine optimization</li>
                <li>Very competitive price</li>
            </ol>
        </p>
    </article>

</section>  

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to close those `<a>` tags.

```
<li><a href="index.html">Home</li>
```

Should be

```
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
```

The same goes for other `<a>` tags.